# Developing and loading Excel Addin using c++

Tags: excel-addins, xll

I have built a NEW/empty Add-in for excel(.xll) 64bit. I am running Win10 on a virtual machine through VMWare, using VS2019, Excel 2013. When I load the Addin I get a not a Valid Add-in error. I was able to convert an old 32bit to 64bit which loaded and worked without a hitch. I matched all the values in Properties, and the code compiles with no warnings or errors but it will not load into excel, Just gives the not a valid add-in error.

When I checked the dependencies, I am missing ext-ms-win-oobe-query-l1-1-0.dll which I cannot find anywhere, but the same was also true for the add-in I converted which loads into excel perfectly.

thanks for the help.

Comment: When you say 'empty' what do you mean? Do you have a xlAutoOpen() entry point?

Comment: by empty I meant blank which should still be accepted by Excel but there would be no functions to register. yes, had xlAutoOpen(). As it is, after tinkering last night I think I found my problem.

Upon creating the new project vs adds compiled headers, I modified the setting to use no PHs. Also added stdafx.h to the compiled header file entry. It compiled fine as was accepted by Excel. Now I will add some functionality to see if it truly works.

Comment: Could I politely suggest that rolling your own XLL from scratch is not much fun and it's better to use a C++ (assuming you're using C++) layer like [xlOil] (https://xloil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/xlOil_Cpp/index.html) (which I wrote) or [xlladdins](https://github.com/xlladdins/xll) (which I didn't write).